# MKMapView annotations - change pin with dot

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkpolyline, mkpointannotation

I have a tracing tool, which checks whether the car reaches some predefined locations.

Currently, when the car reaches location, I use MKPointAnnotation and add a pin at that location. However, I don't want pin. I want a dot.

Is there a way to achieve it? Below is the code that adds pin.

```
- (void) addPin:(NSArray *)locations
 {
     self.location = [locations lastObject];
     self.locationCoordinate2D = self.location.coordinate;
     MKPointAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
     newAnnotation.coordinate = self.locationCoordinate2D;
     [mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `MKUserLocationView` class which provides the dot that you see for your current location cannot be initialised without using private APIs, but you may be interested in [SVPulsingAnnotationView](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPulsingAnnotationView), an open-source replica of this class that you could customise to your taste.

If this is not what you are looking for, you can draw a custom annotation yourself using CoreGraphics by subclassing [MKAnnotationView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Alternatively, you can use the `image` property of a MKAnnotationView to use a custom image for the annotation.  You may also find [the iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html) for creating custom annotations on maps useful.

Comment: It isn't the blue pin for current location. These pins are added by me using MKPointAnnotation. I am able to add "n" number of pins. But, I want to replace pins with dots.

Comment: OK, I considered the current location annotation to look like a dot.  I've updated my answer.